# NiceTabular: Vertical rules are being drawn through blocks

Tags: rules, block, nicematrix

I am making a table with dotted vertical lines, so I am using the NiceTabular environment instead of the tabular environment. I expect the vertical lines not to be drawn within the \Block that I am using (as mentioned in the documentation https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix/nicematrix.pdf p. 7 at the bottom), but this seems not to be the case.

How do I remove the dotted lines from the \Block? This is my code, which I'm running in Overleaf:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{|c ||c:c:c||}
    \hline
    & \Block{1-3}{Resources} & & \\
    & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline \hline
    Part 1 & a & b& c\\
    \hline
    Part 2 & d & e & f\\
    \hline
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The resulting table is [image: table with dotted lines through block], and I expected no dotted lines through 'Resources'.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was a bug which has been solved in the version 6.2 (2021-09-09) of nicematrix.

---

However, if you are stuck with an old version or if you want another type of dotted rule, you can draw the dotted rules (or whatever rule you want) with Tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{|c||ccc||}
\Hline
& \Block{1-3}{Resources} & & \\
& 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \Hline \Hline
Part 1 & a & b& c\\
\Hline
Part 2 & d & e & f\\
\Hline
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw [dotted] (2-|3) -- (last-|3) (2-|4) -- (last-|4) ; 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Great, thank you! Looking forward to the improved version of nicematrix.

Answer (score 5):

With new table package `tabularray` is also simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,3-Z}, 
             vline{3,4}={dashed},
             colspec={|c||ccc||}
             }
        & \SetCell[c=3]{c}
          Resources &   &   \\
        & 1         & 2 & 3 \\
    \hline
Part 1  & a         & b & c \\
Part 2  & d         & e & f \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
With `tabularray` package version 2021N and newest, is possible to draw vertical lines cross double hlines (see L.J.R. comment below). This enables option `belowpos=1` (see MWE below):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{Example when vertical lines crossover double horizontal lines}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,3-Z},
             vline{1,2,Z}={1}{-}{belowpos=1}, %<---
             vline{2,Z}={2}{-}{belowpos=1}, %<---
             vline{3,4}={dashed}, 
             colspec={ c ccc },
             }
        & \SetCell[c=3]{c}
          Resources &   &   \\
        & 1         & 2 & 3 \\
    \hline
Part 1  & a         & b & c \\
Part 2  & d         & e & f \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With the coming version 2021N of `tabularray` package, you can make vlines cross double hlines by setting `belowpos=1`.  This feature is already included in `tabularray.sty` you downloaded yesterday.

Comment: @L.J.R., thank you very much for information. I would correct answer when  new version of package will be official available.

Comment: How could I set its caption?

Comment: @alper, on the same way as at any other (classic) tables. far example, after `\begin{table}` insert `\caption{<caption text>}`.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of `nicematrix` (v. 6.2 of 2021-09-09) solves that bug. The blocks are now respected by the dotted rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{|c ||c:c:c||}
    \hline
    & \Block{1-3}{Resources} & & \\
    & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline \hline
    Part 1 & a & b& c\\
    \hline
    Part 2 & d & e & f\\
    \hline
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]